# Matrix for linear transformation in a base

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $ T_w: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} / T_w(z) = z + w \overline{z}$ with $ w = a + \dot{\imath} b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

If $B = \{1, \dot{\imath}\}$ is a base of $\mathbb{C}$ find the matrix for $T_w$ in said base.

I am having trouble thinking this problem, how do I represent the vectors? As (1, 0) and (0, 1)? If so $T_{(0,1)}(x+\dot{\imath}y) = (x+y)*(1, 0) + (x+y)*(0, 1)$ and then I don't know how to write the matrix.

Sorry for the bad english.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There appear to be typos in your question. As written, the transformation $\ T_w\ $ is *affine*, but not *linear*, so only its linear part $\ z\mapsto \overline{w}z\ $ can be properly represented by a matrix.

Comment: Also, in your example, if $\ z=x+iy\ $, then $\ x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\ $, $\ x=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}\ $, and $\ x+y=\frac{z+\overline{z}+i(\overline{z}-z)}{2}\ $, so what you have written down for $\ T_{(0,1)}\ $ (assuming $\ (0,1)\ $ represents the imaginary number $\ i\ $) is $\ \left(\frac{z+\overline{z}+i(\overline{z}-z)}{2}\right)(1+i)\ $, which *is* linear, but nothing like the transformation $\ T_w\ $ you originally defined.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes it's a typo, very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of the transformation's matrix are given by  the coordinates of the images of the basis vectors with respect to those same basis vectors.  Thus, when the basis vectors of $\ \mathbb{C}\ $, considered as a vector space over $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, are $\ 1\ $ and $\ i\ $, the first column of the matrix is formed from the coordinates of $\ T_w(1)=1+w=1+a+ib\ $, and the second column from the coordinates of $\ T_w(i)=i-iw=b+(1-a)i\  $. The coordinates of $\ T_w(1)\ $ with respect to the basis are therefore $\ 1+a\ $ and $\ b\ $, and the first column of the transformation's matrix is
$$
\pmatrix{1+a\\b}\ .
$$
Try working out the second column for yourself, and if you need reassurance that you've got the correct answer, post it as a comment.

Comment: Would the second column be $\pmatrix{b\\1-a}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 0):

A typical vector of that vector space is represented as $a+bi$. Also, the transformation is given by $\textsf{T}_w(z) = w + \overline{w}z$ for a fixed $w\in\mathbb C$. So, in order to obtain the matrix representation of $\textsf{T}_w$ with respect to $B$ we need to write the vectors $\textsf{T}_w(1)$ and $\textsf{T}_w(i)$ as a linear combination of $1$ and $i$. Let me help you with the first one:
$$\textsf{T}_w(1) = w + \overline{w} = 2\Re(w)\cdot 1 + 0\cdot i,$$
therefore, the first column of your desired matrix is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\Re(w) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$